# Testing code that depends on Ids returned from a query

Tags: apex, unit-test, salesforce-id

I have the following class:

```
public static List<Account> getSchools(String searchKey, String excludedSchoolIds) {
    if (searchKey.length() < 3) {
       return new List<Account>();
    }

    String currentSearch = searchKey + '%';
    List<String> excludedIds = excludedSchoolIds.split('\\,');
    Set<String> excludedSchools = new Set<String>(excludedIds);
    List<Account> schools = [SELECT Name, ParentId, Parent.Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :currentSearch LIMIT 5];

    for (Integer i = schools.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (excludedSchools.contains(String.valueOf(schools.get(i).Id))) {
            schools.remove(i);
        }
    }

    return schools;
}
```

I am writing a test class like so:

```
@isTest static void getSchoolsWhereSearchLengthGreaterThanThree_Test() {
    List<Account> schools = unitTestHelper.createAccounts('acc', 5, false);
    insert schools;

    String searchKey = schools.get(0).Name.substring(0, 3);
    List<Account> schoolResults = CreateSupportCaseController.getSchools(searchKey, NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE);
}
```

The problem I'm having is running the if block within the for loop. List schools (right before the for loop in getSchools) queries my org for Accounts that match the searchKey param. When I create my test class, I don't know how to make it possible that one of the school Ids created from the unit test helper will match an Id from the actual org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may guide you. I made some small adjustments but I believe the issue is in your `createAccounts` method which you do not show.

The following passes all tests and provides appropriate coverage. Not I did not write a test for a search length < 3

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class mySchools {
    //Added as an override when not excluding anything
    public static List<Account> getSchools(String searchKey) {
        return getSchools(searchKey,'');
    }

    public static List<Account> getSchools(String searchKey, String excludedSchoolIds) {
        if (string.isBlank(searchKey) || searchKey.length() < 3) {
            return new List<Account>();
        }

        String currentSearch = searchKey + '%';
        Set<String> excludedSchools = excludedSchoolIds == null ? New Set<String>() : New Set<String>(excludedSchoolIds.split('\\,'));
        List<Account> schools = [SELECT Name, ParentId, Parent.Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :currentSearch LIMIT 5];

        for (Integer i = schools.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (excludedSchools.contains(String.valueOf(schools.get(i).Id))) {
                schools.remove(i);
            }
        }

        return schools;
    }
}
```

**Test Methods** (Account creation is just an example. You can still use your method but this shows you what names work)

```
@IsTest
private class mySchools_Tests {
    @isTest static void resultExcluded() {
        List<Account> schools = New Account[]{
                New Account(Name='A Test A'),
                New Account(Name='B Test B'),
                New Account(Name='C Test C'),
                New Account(Name='D Test D'),
                New Account(Name='E Test E')
        };
        insert schools;

        String searchKey = schools[0].Name.substring(0, 3);
        List<Account> schoolResults = mySchools.getSchools(searchKey, schools[0].Id);

        System.assertEquals(true,schoolResults.isEmpty(),'The matching school was returned when it was specifically excluded by Id');
    }

    @isTest static void resultReturned() {
        List<Account> schools = New Account[]{
                New Account(Name='A Test A'),
                New Account(Name='B Test B'),
                New Account(Name='C Test C'),
                New Account(Name='D Test D'),
                New Account(Name='E Test E')
        };
        insert schools;

        String searchKey = schools[0].Name.substring(0, 3);
        List<Account> schoolResults = mySchools.getSchools(searchKey);

        System.assertEquals(false,schoolResults.isEmpty(),'The matching school list was empty');
        System.assertEquals(schools[0].Id,schoolResults[0].Id);

    }

    @isTest static void resultsReturned() {
        List<Account> schools = New Account[]{
                New Account(Name='Test A'),
                New Account(Name='Test B'),
                New Account(Name='Test C'),
                New Account(Name='Test D'),
                New Account(Name='Test E')
        };
        insert schools;

        String searchKey = schools[0].Name.substring(0, 3);
        List<Account> schoolResults = mySchools.getSchools(searchKey);

        System.assertEquals(5,schoolResults.size(),'The matching school list was not the expected size');

    }
}
```

Your main method code can also be simplified to (a quick simplification):

```
    public static List<Account> getSchools(String searchKey, String excludedSchoolIds) {
        if (string.isBlank(searchKey) || searchKey.length() < 3) {
            return new List<Account>();
        }

        String currentSearch = searchKey + '%';
        Set<String> excludedSchools = excludedSchoolIds == null ? New Set<String>() : New Set<String>(excludedSchoolIds.split('\\,'));
        return [SELECT Name, ParentId, Parent.Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :currentSearch AND (NOT Id In :excludedSchools) LIMIT 5];

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for that simplification. Works perfectly!

Comment: I posted the test class that worked. In my original test class, I wasn't passing the second argument of excludedIds. Let me know if you would like more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you not to adjust your unit tests according data in salesforce environment, but always create your own data set per specific scenario.

One of the approaches would be to create more accounts, which will behave like "excluded" in your unit test. 
In that case, you will be able to test, that excluded accounts are not returned.

For example (pseudocode):

```
@isTest static void getSchoolsWhereSearchLengthGreaterThanThree_Test() {
    List<Account> schools = unitTestHelper.createAccounts('acc', 1, false);
    insert schools;

    Map<Id, Account> excluded_accounts;
    excluded_accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
                          unitTestHelper.createAccounts('acc', 3, false)
                        );

    String excludeIds = String.join(new List<String>(excluded_accounts.keySet(), ',');
    String searchKey = schools.get(0).Name.substring(0, 3);
    Test.startTest();
        List<Account> schoolResults = CreateSupportCaseController.getSchools(searchKey, excludeIds);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEquals(1,
                        schoolResults.size(),
                        'There should be 1 account(s) returned from 4,'
                      + 'because 3 are excluded by ids, but there are not: '
                      + JSON.stringify(schoolResults) );
    //Other check to confirm that excluded accounts are not here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Kurunve. However, when I run the unit test it still does not test the if block. I think the reason is that the Ids from the created accounts in the test class will never match the Ids in the actual query in the apex class. Any thoughts there?

Comment: There may be some problems with 15/18 id representation/comparison, so you can cast your input to set of strings, and then each string to id type, and the do contains. Also  I suggest you to double check your input parameters (f.e., why split as "\\,", why not just comma ? And last option would be to generate 1 account in first cycle, not 5, because your method can query no more then 5 accounts

Comment: I had read that you have to use regex with split so that is why I was using the '\\,'. I changed the first account creation to 1 and made a few minor tweaks to the test class and can confirm that it is getting me 100% code coverage. I couldn't have done it without you! I'd like to post the final solution, but want to give you credit for the answer. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here was the final test class.

```
@isTest static void getSchoolsWhereSearchLengthGreaterThanThree_Test() {
    List<Account> schools = unitTestHelper.createAccounts('acc', 1, false);
    insert schools;

    List<Account> excludedSchools = unitTestHelper.createAccounts('acc', 3, false);
    insert excludedSchools;
    Map<String, Account> excluded_accounts = new Map<String, Account>();

    for (Account excludedSchool : excludedSchools) {
        excluded_accounts.put(String.valueOf(excludedSchool.Id), excludedSchool);        
    }

    String excludeIds = String.join(new List<String>(excluded_accounts.keySet()), ',');
    String searchKey = schools.get(0).Name.substring(0, 3);
    Test.startTest();
        List<Account> schoolResults = CreateSupportCaseController.getSchools(searchKey, excludeIds);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEquals(1, schoolResults.size());
}
```